# Constructing the asymptotes of a hyperbola by compass and straightedge.

Tags: reference-request, conic-sections, plane-geometry, geometric-construction

Is it possible to construct the asymptotes of a hyperbola from the points on the hyperbola by compass and straightedge alone? And if so, how to construct them?

I have no idea how to approach the first question. It seems it should be possible as it is similar to constructing a tangent to an ellipse, but I haven't been able to adjust such a construction to work for the asymptotes of a hyperbola. An illustration or a reference would be welcome.

Comment: What would be the "givens" of the construction? Do you mean, for example, that we would be "given" the points on the hyperbola, so for example I could pick any eleven points on the hyperbola and attempt to base my construction of the asymptote on those points?

Answer (score 2):

See in https://fr.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130810183100AArTMlg **Warning**, not the first solution but the second one, by Pope, which constructs the hyperbola's centre first, which looks compulsory. For fully understanding it, you need to have seen a minimum of properties of what is called a diameter in a conic curve, whose definition I recall:

When a line is moved paralelly to itsef, i.e., keeping the same direction (D), the midpoints of its points of intersection with the conic section belong to a same line (D') ; if the conic section possesses a centre (this is the case here, or for an ellipse, but not for a parabola) the centre belongs to this diameter. The line with direction (D) passing through the centre is called the conjugate diameter of (D').

Comment: I don't think this algorithm is specific to rectangular hyperbolas.

Comment: Question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3784473/construct-the-focii-and-asymptotes-with-compass-and-ruler-given-a-non-rectangul?newreg=94489116d2344398a3c177ec7243b487 suggests it may actually be specific to rectangular hyperbolas.. ?

Comment: @irbanana Thanks, I must have a closer look.