# ruler-straightedge construction of foci of hyperbola

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Assuming that we are given a hyperbola and we know its vertices, asymptotes, and semi-major axes, is it possible to construct its foci using only a straightedge and a compass? It is easy to calculate the distance of the foci from the center using the equation of the hyperbola, but I would like to know if there is a purely geometrical way to do it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3784473/construct-the-focii-and-asymptotes-with-compass-and-ruler-given-a-non-rectangul goes even deeper than that

Comment: Look at the figure "Standard forms of a hyperbola" on [this website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section)